# Node.js Login to blog site and Create new post

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to login to blogfa.com (a persian blog service) and create a new post by node.js

To do that i use request.js to post login site and go this url "`/Desktop/Post.aspx?action=newpost`" and post a new content

here is code i got so far :

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var j = request.jar();
    request = request.defaults({ jar : j }); //it will make the session default for every request
    //...
    var headers = {
                 'User-Agent':       'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.89 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1750.48',
                'Content-Type':     'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
              };

    request({
        url:"http://blogfa.com/Desktop/login.aspx",
        method:"POST",
        form:{uid:"demoblog1",pwd:"test"},
        headers: headers,
        followRedirect:true
    },
    function(error,response,body){
      console.log(body);
    });
```

Problem i have its,  i cant login in to the site .

i dont why not working ! i used jar for cookie , posted user and password , also set headers.

here is `runnable` code you can test :

http://code.runnable.com/Vc7EnmyVlgRa1Hx-/blog-login-for-node-js

**Update**

**Request Cookies**

```
 .ASPXBLOG  BC045A0CD184FEA10D91561EB67A302F1E036D88E50CE4264E4ABD003
__utma  36873331.1996897518.1435135939.1437159460.1439563539.7
__utmz  36873331.1437159460.6.6.utmcsr=chat.delgarm.com|utmccn=(referral)
pubset  ar=1&z=12600&ds=0&cmt=0&cats=0&tag=0&nu=1&bt=dGVzdCB
ten 67145377
```

Answer (score 0):

By default `request` does not follow redirects for non-GET requests, which is what is happening in this case. So set [`followAllRedirects: true`](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) in your `request()` options and it should work fine.

Comment: As you can see my code , i added before `followRedirect:true` option , in request. but still not working.

Comment: It's `followAllRedirects`, *not* `followRedirect` (which defaults to `true` anyway).

Comment: sorry , my bad :( after i set `followAllRedirects` its still not working , and i think problem is cookie not saving , for test i disabled cookie in my browser and try to login ,  i got same error !

Comment: The server is probably generating a token (`_tx`) or other information that is currently missing from your form. So you'll have to get the login page first, parse it with cheerio, then insert the token or whatever other values into your form when you submit it.

Comment: there is parameter `r` and its send by query string , when i try to login it redirect to url `Desktop/login.aspx?r=2767051` , do you think i need send this query string ?